# Suppose that $p$ is prime and $a\in\mathbb{Z}_p$.Show that $x^p+a$ can be factored into linear factors in $\mathbb Z_p [x].$

Tags: ring-theory

Suppose that $p$ is prime and $a\in\mathbb{Z}_p$.Show that $x^p+a$ can be factored into linear factors in $\mathbb{Z}_p [x]$.

I'm not sure where to start for this problem, if anyone can help, give me ideas, etc, I would very much appreciate it!

Comment: The map $b\mapsto b^p$ is injective and thus surjective on the base field.

Comment: ... and $(X+b)^p = X^p + b^p$

Answer (score 5):

$$x^p+a=x^p+a^p =(x+a)^p$$ $             $

Comment: how did you get your result? Can you be more specific to your reasoning to distributing the p to a?

Comment: @user110655 You mean $a^p=a$? This is Fermat's little theorem